# deleting a plugin (not a user defined) command?

Tags: command, fzf

I am using the fzf plugin which has a command called `:Windows`. Very often I type `:W` instead of `:w` when trying to write and it is very annoying. I would like to remove the command, since I do not use it very much, and have tried putting

```
delcommand Windows
```

in my `vimrc` which did not work, `E184: No such user-defined command: Windows` so I tried put it in the `after` directory because to my knowledge, vim processes stuff there after plugins have been loaded. But that did not work either. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not entirely sure deleting this command is a great idea you can do it using an autocommand like this in your vimrc:

```
augroup deletePluginCommand
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * delcommand Windows
augroup END
```

If you are not familiar with autocommands, they are a way to trigger some code on an event (see [`:h autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd)) and here we use the event `VimEnter` which is trigger once all the initialization scripts are done ([`:h VimEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter)).

**EDIT** With a solution which seems less intrusive to me:

Maybe instead of deleting the command you could use another trick:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> W (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^W$')? 'w' : 'W'
```

This command line abbreviation will replace `W` by `w` in the command line only if the content of the command line is `W` this way when you use `:W` you will not trigger `:Windows` but `:w` instead.

Comment: @FirstUser You already accepted my answer but maybe you should check my edit, I think it is a better solution than deleting the command altogether because maybe one day `:Windows` will be useful to you.